# activerecord-import gem: has_many through issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activerecord-import

With help of [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) I'm trying to save list of records with `has_many through` children in one query.

my models:

```
class Mailing < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :mailing_modifications
  has_many :modifications, through: :mailing_modifications

end

class Modification < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :mailing_modifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :mailings, through: :mailing_modifications

end

class MailingModification < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :mailing
  belongs_to :modification

end
```

My code for saving:

```
mailing = Mailing.new
mailing.modifications.build
mailings << mailing
Mailing.import(mailings, recursive: true)
```

But I'm get an error `NoMethodError: undefined method modification_id=' for #<Modification:0x00000006eb01d0>`

Comment: have you create mailing_modifications model

Comment: @Mukesh sure, added to questions

Comment: @PavelBabin did you find a solution?